# Proof of a very intuitive result

Tags: calculus

I can see geometrically that the below result is correct, but I couldn't prove it formally:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left[(x-\tau_0)\lambda(t+x)-\int_{t+\tau_0}^{t+x}\lambda(s)ds\right]=\infty$$
where $t$ and $\tau_0$ are positive real numbers, $\lambda(s)$ is a positive function such that $\lambda'(s)>0$ and $\lambda(\infty)=\infty$.

Comment: I think you may write $(x-\tau_0)\lambda(t+x)$ as $\int_{t+\tau_0}^{t+x}\lambda(t+x)ds$

Comment: use integration by parts (by writing the function you integrate as $x'\lambda(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity that you study can be written alternatively
$$\int_{\tau_0}^x (\lambda(t+x)-\lambda(t+y))dy = \int_{\tau_0}^\infty 1_{[y \le x]} \times(\lambda(t+x)-\lambda(t+y))dy .$$
The functions to be integrated are non-negative, depend in a non-decreasing way of the parameter $x$, and tend pointwise to $+\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. Therefore, the monotone convergence theorem applies.